# Effective chaining using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a pretty simple problem which I could hack away at, but I'd rather do things more efficiently in R using things like `dplyr.` That being said, this question is probably dead simple to someone who is fairly good with that package.

I have a dataframe, 3 columns and 30 rows (for simplicity).  I'd like to calculate the 87th percentile score. After that, I'd like to normalize that score to within a range within 0 and 1. Pretty straightforward: recall normalization is done via

[image]

So the second line below is taking advantage of the power of `dplyr`.

```
DF <- data.frame(matrix(runif(90, min=0, max=100), ncol=3,nrow=30))
DF_87th_percentile <- DF %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(quantile(., c(0.87)))
```

Afterwards, I have the 87th percentile score calculated, but then I stumble and start creating `min` and `max` variables,

```
min <- apply(DF, 2, min)
max <- apply(DF, 2, max)
```

and then

```
normalized_score <- (DF_87th_percentile - min) / (max - min)
```

Is there some way I can rewrite the last parts using `dplyr`? Like, chain the last parts in perhaps? My efforts have been no good up to now. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I think he wants to normalize the 87th percentile scores (3 values), rather than the original variables.

Comment: I would like to normalize the 87th percentile scores -- transform these scores to being within the interval [0, 1]

Answer (score 2):

You need to write the normalization as a function in order to use it in a `dplyr` chain. For example:

```
mynorm <- function(x) { (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) }

DF <- data.frame(matrix(runif(90, min=0, max=100), ncol=3,nrow=30))

DF %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(quantile(., c(0.87)))) %>%
    mynorm()
```

Example results:

```
  X1 X2       X3
1  0  1 0.986836
```

Comment: I think you want `summarise_each(funs(quantile(., c(0.87), na.rm=TRUE)))`. The way you have it written now, `na.rm=TRUE` is being passed to `c()`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. Would the min and max now be getting calculated on the summary object rather than on `DF`?

Comment: Yes, that's right. As I understand it, that's what he wants to do.

Comment: No, I'd like the min and max to be calculated on the `DF`, which is the sensible thing to do.

Comment: It seemed odd that you would want to normalize only on the scores, but your response to my comment on the question implied (to me) that that was what you wanted to do. If you want the 87th percentile scores normalized on the overall data frame, use BondedDust's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought you could just modify the original call:

```
normalized_score <- DF %>% 
     summarise_each(funs( (quantile(., c(0.87))-min(.) )/(max(.)-min(.)) ))
 normalized_score
         X1        X2        X3
1 0.9081882 0.8308022 0.9266201
```